# constraints that are unique / references columns of another table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have two tables. In `table_b`, I want to reference two columns (not primary key) from `table_a` (as when I join the two tables, I want to join on both `product_id` and `group_id`). I also want the combo of those two keys to be unique. Is this foreign key essentially a composite key if I don't have the primary key id on `table_b`? Does it make sense for me to create this foreign key in `table_b` (even though its not referencing primary keys from `table_a`?

Does it make sense to have two constraints like below on `table_b`?

```
CREATE TABLE table_a(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id VARCHAR, // can be null
  group_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE table_b(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  group_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_key FOREIGN KEY(product_id, group_id) REFERENCES table_a(product_id, group_id)
  CONSTRAINT unique_id UNIQUE (product_id, group_id);
)
```

Note that `table_a` `product_id` can be null, but not that of in `table_b`. All references from table_a in table_b will only include if `product_id` and `group_id` is not null. Thanks!

Comment: I am stuck at this sentence:  "I want to reference two columns (not primary key)."  I cannot imagine a scenario where referencing two *text* columns would be preferable to a nice, simple, integer primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys need to reference keys but not necessarily *primary* keys. So you'd need to include a unique constraint in `table_a`.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
             (id serial,
              product_id varchar,
              group_id varchar
                       NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              UNIQUE (product_id,
                      group_id));

CREATE TABLE table_b
             (id serial,
              product_id varchar
                         NOT NULL,
              group_id varchar
                       NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (product_id,
                           group_id)
                          REFERENCES table_a
                                     (product_id,
                                      group_id),
              UNIQUE (product_id,
                      group_id));
```

Comment: `varchar(1)` is not the same as `varchar `. It’s also unlikely to be useful; a variable length string with a maximum length of 1 can’t hold many distinct values.

Comment: @Bohemian: Habit. I find `varchar`s without length confusing. Changed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t create a FK from table_b to table_a, because there actually isn’t such a relationship due to table_a allowing product_id to be null.

So just

```
create table table_a (
    id serial primary key
    product_id varchar,
    group_id varchar qnot null,
    unique (product_id, group_id)
    foreign key (product_id, group_id)
      references table_b (product_id, group_id)
)
```

It looks likely that table_b should be folded into table_a, which I recommend you do; 2-way FKs are usually a design smell.